# Type Of Object In C#

Tags: c#

(Excuse me, my English language is bad)
I have three classes in c#,all of them have a method "SaveObject",
in GUI  I want to call these methods,So i write this code:

```
private void save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   switch(sender.GetType().Name.Tostring())
   {
     case "ClassOne" :
                       ClassOne obj1 = sender as ClassOne;
                       obj1.SaveObject();
                       break;
     case "ClassTwo" :
                       ClassTwo obj2 = sender as ClassTwo;
                       obj2.SaveObject();
                       break;
     case "ClassThree" :
                       ClassThree obj3 = sender as ClassThree;
                       obj3.SaveObject();
                       break;
   }
}
```

is there any way to write this code better than above;

Answer (score 4):

Have all three classes implement a single interface: `ISaveable`, or something. Add a single method to that interface: `SaveObject`, and implement that method in each of the three classes (which you really already have).

Then you can replace the above with this:

```
private void save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ISaveable saveable = (ISaveable)sender;
    saveable.SaveObject();
}
```

Comment: Surely you'd change the method parameter to `ISaveable too so it's compile time checked not run-time?

Comment: If that's an option, yes, absolutely. It isn't always.

Comment: It looks like this method is used as an event handler, and it's trying to call `SaveObject()` on the event sender.  If that's the case then `sender` must be of type `object` to match the `EventHandler` delegate type.

Answer (score 1):

You should have the three classes inherit my an `interface` (`IMyInterface`) with a method `SaveObject`, and then cast `sender` to `IMyInterface` and from there call `SaveObject()`.

I'll add that C# has the `is` operator.

```
if (sender is ClassOne)
```

but then you can't use the switch.

Ah and `Name` already is a `string`, so you don't need a `ToString`

Answer (score 1):

If you can't create an interface (perhaps because you have no control over the classes) and are using C# 4, you can use the new dynamic capabilities:

```
((dynamic)sender).SaveObject();
```

If you can't create an interface and can't use `dynamic`, you will have to use Reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is!

There are two options here.

1. If the logic of `SaveObject()` is the same for all three classes
2. If the logic is different

In the first case, you create what is called an abstract class, and the other classes "inherit" it. This means that the `SaveObject` method is create once, and you don't have to write it in all three classes.

```
public abstract class ClassBase
{
    public void SaveObject()
    {
        // save logic goes here
    }
}

public class ClassOne : ClassBase
{
    // other methods and properties; do the same for ClassTwo and ClassThree
}
```

Now you can do this in your event handler:

```
if (sender is ClassBase)
{
    ((ClassBase) sender).SaveObject();
}
```

In the second case, where the logic is different among all three classes, you create an "interface" and your other classes will "implement" it. This means that they each MUST declare their own `SaveObject()` method.

```
public interface IClass
{
    void SaveObject(); // use the signature only here -- no logic; you cannot use access modifiers like "public"
}

public class ClassOne : IClass
{
    // other stuff

    public void SaveObject()
    {
        // save logic for this class
    }
}

public class ClassTwo : IClass
{
    // other stuff

    public void SaveObject()
    {
        // different save logic for this class
    }
}
```

Now you can create methods like this:

```
public void PerformSave(IClass myClass)
{
    myClass.SaveObject();
}
```

…and it will work whether you pass in an instance of `ClassOne`, `ClassTwo` or `ClassThree`.

In your case, however, you just have an argument of type `object`. You can do this:

```
private void save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is IClass)
    {
        ((IClass) sender).SaveObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you implement an interface with the 'SaveObject()' method and inherit this interface for each of your classes. Then you can just perform a cast and call the method.

```
public interface ISaveObject
{
    void SaveObject();
}

public class ClassOne : ISaveObject
{
    public void SaveObject()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to expose common interface with method SaveObject() for all 3 classes, then cast your sender to that interface and call method.
Or you can take a look on Strategy/Command patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The problem with your code is it will break if you rename a class by doing any kind of refactoring. I would write it as:

```
private void save(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (sender is ClassOne)
   {
       ((ClassOne)sender).SaveObject();
   }
   else if (sender is ClassTwo)
   {
       ((ClassTwo)sender).SaveObject();
   }
   else if (sender is ClassThree)
   {
       ((ClassThree)sender).SaveObject();
   }
   else
   {
       throw new Exception("Unknown type");
   }
}
```

An interface might be a better solution though. Why not just put an interface on all of the classes with a member called `SaveObject`, and just case it to the interface?

```
public class ClassOne : IPersistable
{
}

public class ClassTwo : IPersistable
{
}

//etc...

public interface IPersistable
{
    void SaveObject();
}
```

Then:

```
var persistable = (IPersistable)sender;
persistable.SaveObject();
```